# Push Notification with Firebase not working while app is active

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

First of all sorry for my bad english.

I'm working on an Android App which functions correctly. However, I have a problem when receiving push notifications using Firebase.
Contrary to other asked questions, my device correctly receives push notifications while the App is in the background or stopped. I do not receive notification, however, if the app is open and in use.

Here is my code:

Manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

...

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.FirebaseLoader"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity

        ...

        </activity>
        <service android:name=".app.NotificationListener"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

NotificationListener class:

```
public class NotificationListener extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    //When the service is started
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //Opening sharedpreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Getting the firebase id from sharedpreferences
        String id = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, null);

        //Creating a firebase object
        Firebase firebase = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_APP + id);

        //Adding a valueevent listener to firebase
        //this will help us to  track the value changes on firebase
        firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            //This method is called whenever we change the value in firebase
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //Getting the value from firebase
                //We stored none as a initial value
                String msg = snapshot.child("msg").getValue().toString();
                String title = snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();

                //So if the value is none we will not create any notification
                if (msg.equals("none"))
                    return;

                //If the value is anything other than none that means a notification has arrived
                //calling the method to show notification
                //String msg is containing the msg that has to be shown with the notification
                showNotification(title, msg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("The read failed: ", firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    private void showNotification(String title, String msg){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://autofreunde-isartal.de"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(msg);
//        builder.setSound();
        builder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 300);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}
```

FirebaseLoader class

```
public class FirebaseLoader extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

MainActivity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

... (fragment loading method) ...

    if (!isRegistered()) {
        registerDevice();
    } else {
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationListener.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private boolean isRegistered() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.REGISTERED, false);
}

private void registerDevice() {
    //Creating a firebase object
    Firebase firebase = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_APP);

    //Pushing a new element to firebase it will automatically create a unique id
    Firebase newFirebase = firebase.push();

    //Creating a map to store name value pair
    Map<String, String> val = new HashMap<>();

    //pushing msg = none in the map
    val.put("msg", "none");
    val.put("title", "none");

    //saving the map to firebase
    newFirebase.setValue(val);

    //Getting the unique id generated at firebase
    String firebaseId = newFirebase.getKey();

    //Finally we need to implement a method to store this unique id to our server
    sendIdToServer(firebaseId);
}

private void sendIdToServer(final String firebaseId) { }
```

(in MainActivity I implemented 4 fragments, you can select by menu)

I hope someone can help me find this error.
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you're missing certain declarations inside your manifest?

```
        <service android:name=".notification.MessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".notification.InstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Therefore have you implemented all the relevant classes?

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: thanks, you saved my day. I didn't know that the push notification is generated from another task while the app is stopped than while it's running.